# What would happen in a C programm [ getchar() ] like this if i only press ENTER?

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
char ch;
ch = getchar() ;
```

What will the input be if i only press Enter without typing any other character? If possible explain why?

**EDIT:**

I know it inputs a new line character but i would like to know why input '\n' when if i press 'a' it inputs 'a'? If there is any list where it shows the inputs of ENTER,SPACE.TAB etc.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Tried it .... asked the question only to know the theory behind it. Why downvote it????

Comment: If you hit SPACE, you get a space, if you hit tab, you get a tab character '\t'.  It's not a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I assume you're familiar with [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)?

This is what you're getting. `getchar()` is returning you an integer (ASCII) value for whatever character you input. So for example, if you have this code:

```
void main()
{
    char ch;
    while(1){
      ch = getchar();
      printf("%c, %#x\n",ch,(int)ch);
    }
    return;
}
```

You could input say '4' and see it represented as 
`4, 0x34 (integer representation of '4')`

Likewise this will work with \n or \t or any of the others. If you enter \t you'd see:
`, 0x9`

The character is a tab, so you won't see it show up, but `getchar()` did grab the tab and you can see that it's 0x9 as we would expect.
Does that help? I'm not sure if that's the answer your looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You'd get the newline character - `'\n'`.

Comment: Would this still happen on a Windows machine, where newlines are `\r\n`? Not OP, just curious and I don't have a windows machine to test with right now.